# I can't even with this place (meaning)

Tags: idioms, expressions

In this movie clip ([at 2:01](https://youtu.be/2QKg5SZ_35I?t=2m1s)), actor Jack Black says:

> That was so intense I, like, can't even with this place.

What does he mean he can't even with the place?

Comment: ..or was it "pace"?

Comment: @lebatsnok No, it's 'place'. See https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle-trailer-quotes/

Comment: Did you search for "I can't even meaning"?  [There are many sites that explain it.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-can-t-even)

Comment: OK, usually, in  speech, you would say something like: I can't, like, even [deal] with this place. In this particular case, he skips the verb. Often, one might do that...you don't finish a phrase where you would have actually said: can't even deal or handle this place. Sometimes the "can't even" just dies out and you never get to the verb: "God, I just can't, like, even [missing word replaced by a facial expression] ..... This place...."

Comment: That's the kind of thing he should have done, as an actor, but his timing is off and the director's decided to keep it anyway. Also, ***in the script you would see ellipses here***:...He did not follow those ellipses with his voice though  he sort of did with his expression.

Answer (score 1):

"I can't even" is more typically used as a sentence fragment after some remark, like the person meant to finish the sentence as "I can't even believe that" or "I can't even imagine" or "I can't even talk any more about this." It's often said with frustration or sarcasm as if the speaker can't even finish speaking.

"That was so intense I, like, can't even with this place."
would be more typically said as "This place was so intense, I can't even." In that clip, it's funny because the actor uses the expression without the normal pause at the end, instead filling in "with this place."  It is definitely an unusual construct and indicates (to me) that he is flustered.

Some fun examples of "I can't even": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQ-zy4RoXZY

Answer (score 1):

In the vernacular of young people, "I can't even" is a complete sentence. Sometimes, just saying "I can't" in the right context and with the right *attitude* gets the same point across. (The *attitude* of it is really important.) It embodies a complete lack of being able to handle or process something or someone, of being over and done with something or someone. Appropriate attitudes for the expression include being sassy, frustrated, and/or petty. "I can't" and "I can't even" are used colloquially in this way.

*Brad and Angelina broke up again. Did you hear? I just can't with those two. One day they're broken up, and then the next they're back together. I can't keep track. It's too much to deal with. I can't even.*

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's just making fun of a dialect some people have. Teenage girls are stereotyped to put the word "like" in between most of their words.
In this particular context, I believe he's saying "That was so intense, I hate that place."